# Saving Facebook Profile picture from URL using cURL not working After March 27 ,2018

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Im using the following code:

```
$json_link = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/me?fields=id,picture.width(300).height(280)&access_token=".$accessToken.""; 

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $json_link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$obj = json_decode($output);
$xx=$obj->picture->data->url;
$src=imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($xx));
```

`$obj` returns the following:

```
stdClass Object ( 
    [id] => idxxxxx 
    [picture] => stdClass Object ( 
        [data] => stdClass Object ( 
            [height] => 480 
            [is_silhouette] =>
            [url] => lookaside.facebook.com/platform/profilepic/
            [width] => 415 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

But it is failing on:

```
$xx=$obj->picture->data->url;
$src=imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($xx));
```

I get:

[image]

So fails:

```
imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($xx));
```

It worked fine before March 27, but after graph api update its no longer working.

Comment: $obj return the data from facebook

Comment: stdClass Object ( [id] => idxxxxx [picture] => stdClass Object ( [data] => stdClass Object ( [height] => 480 [is_silhouette] => [url] => https://lookaside.facebook.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&height=320&width=370 [width] => 415 ) ) )

Comment: it returns like this screenshot  : http://prntscr.com/ixf6ss
when i echo the file_get_contents($xx);

Comment: and this line returns this error
imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($xx));

imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format

Comment: You should probably look into using the [sdk](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk).

Comment: I also facing the same kind of issue on FB today.

Answer (score 2):

FB is looking for User-agent information.

```
$User_Agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31';

$request_headers = array();
   $request_headers[] = 'User-Agent: '. $User_Agent;
   $request_headers[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  $r = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
```

It will solve your problem.

Comment: bingo! you saved my day:)

Comment: its get blocked after few minutes

Answer (score 0):

Only put the line: file_put_contents('file.jpg', fopen($obj->picture->data->url, 'r'));

Comment: please avoid answering via one-liners, explain your answer as best as you can